# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: a

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

Here is my code:

```
app.factory('assignmentAttachments', function() {


});

describe("test", function() {
    // arrange variable
    var assignmentAttachments;

    // inject service
     beforeEach(inject(function(_assignmentAttachments_) {
        assignmentAttachments = _assignmentAttachments_;
     })); 

    describe("test", function() {
        it("test", function() {
            // arrange

        })
    });

});
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   assignmentAttachmentsProvider <- assignmentAttachments
>     http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$injector/unpr?p0=assignmentAttachmentsProvider%20%3C-%20assignmentAttachments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have import the module where `assignmentAttachments` is registered. For example, if `assignmentAttachments` is registered in the `app` module, like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.factory('assignmentAttachments', ...});
```

Then you have to import that module in the test:

```
describe("test", function() {
    ...

    beforeEach(module('app')); // <== add this line

    // inject service
    beforeEach(inject(function(_assignmentAttachments_) {
        assignmentAttachments = _assignmentAttachments_;
    })); 
});
```